# How can I search for self in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where selector is variable usualy used to search within previously defined container, but is it possible to construct selector this way to point on this element? In other words what need selector to be equal with in the line below to get container as result?

```
$(selector, container)
```

To give more infomation. The line is used within some function and i'm looking for code that will work in all situations. So let's say we have html as follows

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='some-element'>
  </div>
  <div class='some-other-element'>
  </div>
</div>
```

And script as follows. I know it's possible to put some ifs in function body let's say "if selector == 'self'" or something like that, but i'm wondering if there is some more elegant built-in jquery way?

```
var container = $('.container');
...
do_something = function(selector) {
   var element = $(selector, container);
   ...
}

do_something('.some-element');
do_something('.some-other-element');
do_something('self?'); // <<<< problem
```

Comment: Please provide more information what is `selector` and `container`. `$(selector, container)` will search for `selector` inside `container`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses CSS selectors. As CSS has no notion of context, I don't think there is a way to express *self* as a selector.

Furthermore, `$(foo, bar)` is equal to `$(bar).find(foo)`. But the latter just [finds descendants](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Answer (score 0):

> *what need selector to be equal with in the line below **to get container as result** ?*

You can use `.closest()` method for this:

```
$(selector).closest(container)
```

to get the ***container*** which has the ***selector***.

---

Other than this in your selector you can use `.parent()` to get the container *but not a good idea*:

```js
var selector = $('.selector'),
  container = $('.container'),
  con = $(selector, container).parent();

console.log(con[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  container
  <div class="selector">selector</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you find an element by a selector:

```
var el = $("someSelector");
```

If container is a direct parent of this element, you can find it like this:

```
var container = el.parent();
```

If not, you can traverse through parent elements until you find some specific element:

```
var container = el.closest("containerSelector");
```

You can combine those operations to one statement:

```
$("someSelector").parent();
$("someSelector").closest("containerSelector");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 'addBack' its new to me, but it works the way it adds to the result just last result which is in this case, the result of .find('.container') as Fabian Klötzl pointed out is alias of  $(,'.container'). https://api.jquery.com/addBack/

```
var container = $('.container');

do_something = function(selector) {
   var element = $(selector,container).addBack(selector);
   // just to show it works
   $('.results').append($(element).attr('class')+"<br/>")
}

do_something('.some-element');
do_something('.some-other-element');
do_something('.container');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adax2000/3qLs6o7w/5/